# Translating "They don't call me ... for nothing."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, nombres-propios

In English, there is a phrase "They don't call me ... for nothing." (showing that some nickname someone has has been confirmed by something they just did or are about to do). Is there any equivalent expression in Spanish?

Comment: (showing that some nickname someone has has been confirmed by something they just did or are about to do) ???

Comment: @Eduardo: Sorry if that didn't make sense. As an example, let's say I'm really good at fixing things and people call me "Mr. Fixes-Everything." Then if I just finished fixing something difficult, I might say, "Well, they don't call me 'Mr. Fixes-Everything' for nothing!" Kind of a forced example, but that's the idea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are acceptable translations:

- No me llaman ... por nada.
- No me llaman ... en vano.

Alternatively, you can use the more idiomatic (in Spain):

- Por algo me llaman ...

Comment: +1 `Por algo me llaman...` is also used in Colombia. `No me llaman en vano` is rarely, if ever, used in Colombia.

Comment: It could be idiomatic but it doesn't fit to the question; it has a completely different meaning.

Comment: @CesarGon: After OP's clarification, *Por algo me llaman* would be the best alternative. Upvoting, sorry for the previous comment.

Comment: The first ones are also a little more idiomatic (at least in Argentina) in this form: "No por nada me llaman..." "No en vano me llaman..."

Answer (score 1):

`No me llaman a menos que sea importante` would be an expression often heard in support positions.

UPDATE: After OP's clarification `No me dicen/llaman ... por nada/en vano` would seem to fit OP's question.